# How to round percentage of barchart in MPAndroidChart Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, charts, xamarin.android, mpandroidchart

```
public class YourValueFormatter : IValueFormatter
{


    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }



    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public YourValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###"); // use no decimals
    }

    public String GetFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {

        // This method never called.
        return Math.Round(value)+""; 
    }


}
```

This is how I am setting formatter to data

```
data.SetValueFormatter(new YourValueFormatter());
```

also tried to set it on dataset like this

```
dataset.ValueFormatter=new YourValueFormatter();
```

Tried in many ways but nothing getting work for me.

I want to round bar value like this

2.00 TO 2% (Predefined percentage formatter formate like this 2.0% but I need 2%)

or

420.0 to 420

lib version : `2.2.3.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to inherit from `Java.Lang.Object`, when you implement java interfaces.If you have a look at the build output, you'll find something like:

> Type 'YourValueFormatter' implements IValueFormatter but does not inherit from Java.Lang.Object. It is not supported.

**Correct**

```
public class YourValueFormatter : Java.Lang.Object, IValueFormatter
{
    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public YourValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###"); // use no decimals
    }

    public String GetFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) 
    {
        // This method never called.
        return Math.Round(value)+""; 
    }
}
```

Your `GetFormattedValue` should now get called.